# Error connecting to AWS RDS mariadb instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, mariadb

I have just created an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance and an RDS mariadb instance to go with it. (I'm using the free tier at the moment).

I have turned off the public access to the RDS so that it only is accessible within the same VCS. My EC2 box is in the same the VCS and I want to connect to the database from there.

I installed mariadb-client on my Ubuntu box. I used the endpoint from my RDS Instance page for the RDS box and ran the command:

```
mysql  -P 3306 -u thomas -p -h ******.******.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '******.*****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (-2)
```

host ******.******.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com returns not found.

When I had mis-spelled the server name on my first attempt, I got a (-3) after the error, which I think is interesting. So I googled the error code and found  this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-client.html which tells me about the error code 2005, but nothing about the part in parens.

The docs refer to an include, which I looked up, but found no -2. So:

1) Where do you find the information about the info in parens?

2) Why can't I reach my RDS instance?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro How do you find the IP address of a non-public server? I followed your link, but stil didn't see a -2 or -3.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro has provided bad information.  The sqlstate here is `HY000`, "generic error."  The number in parentheses at the end is the system error, which should not be a negative number.  That's unusual.  If it were a positive number, `perror <number>` would work.

Comment: You can get the IP address with the `host` command, e.g. `host example.com`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot added results of host command.

Comment: You probably need to double-check that hostname in the RDS console.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot went through it multiple times before the post. Like I said, found the one typo, but since then it's been frustrating.

Comment: Understood.  Disregard, for the moment, that the RDS instance is not Internet accessible, and trust my assertion that the DNS records still will be.  Try resolving it from your local desktop machine, using nslookup.  You should still see the (private) IP address returned (publicly) by DNS. You can't access it externally, but you can still learn its IP.  If that works, then you now know the RDS machine's IP, and you have a general DNS issue on your EC2 machine or with your VPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as would be expected, I was a knucklehead. First, I didn't realize this, but the endpoint changed for some reason. I probably changed a setting and it rebuilt it without me asking and gave it a new endpoint name. This is why the nslookup and host commands were failing.

Then, once they starting working, I was going to work on the script I was using to connect and I realized I had left the :3306 at the end of the hostname on the -h parameter. I deleted this and everything started working.

This is what happens when you vote "No" for lobotomies for web developers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the IP address of RDS instance instead of the host name.   See if you can access the port directly, without the client package ie. telnet host 3306.

Also, since they are in the VPC, make sure the subnets match.  That has gotten me before with multiple internal subnets.

Comment: How do you get the IP address of something not accessible from outside? I don't see IP addess in the info.

Comment: You should probably take a look at this (if you have not already),
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html

Make sure the VPC subnets and security groups allow access, and you should be able to find the subnet group, and thus the internal instance IP from there.